# Encontrar las url de un desplegable con python 3.8.1 y bs4 scraping

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. > Busco las url de cada jornada, que es un desplegable. 
   >   he probado con todas las clasess pero nada no consigo obtener las url de este desplegable. 
   >   Ayuda, cuando hago un find_all aparece lo que busco pero cuando intento lo la clase no puedo.

---

```
#! python3

import requests, webbrowser, bs4

print('Searching...')
url_base = 'https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/'
page = requests.get(url_base)
page.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
linkElems = soup.select('ul[role = ".dropdown-menu.dropdown-select"]') 
hrf = []
for cad in linkElems:
    hrf.append("url_base" + cad.get("href"))
    print(hrf)
```

Las `url` finales tienen de añadido la `url_base + '?' id + '=' value` .

En el `Html` hay esto: `id="competitionRoundId", name="competitionRoundId", value="506293"`.

https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506283

Comment: hola alguien que me ayuda porfa, ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los `links` del `dropdown` puedes usar `find_all`. En esta página, hay dos elementos que poseen la `clase dropdown-menu dropdown-select`. Y al que usted quiere hacer referencia, es el elemento 1, o sea el segundo de la lista.

he definido las variables dentro del `loop`, para que veas a que hace referencia cada `item`, puedes obviarlas si quieres, y también el `print`, que solo fue utilizado para mostrar la salida que necesitaba.

```
competition = '?competitionRoundId='
hrf = []
for item in soup.find_all(class_="dropdown-menu dropdown-select")[1]:

    print(item.text+": " ,url_base+competition+item.a.get('data-value')) 

    href = url_base+competition+item.a.get('data-value')
    jornada = item.text
    hrf.append(jornada,href)
```

output:

```
1ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506283
2ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506285
3ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506286
4ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506288
5ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506290
6ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506291
7ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506289
8ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506287
9ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506294
10ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506296
11ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506297
12ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506295
13ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506300
14ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506312
15ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506298
16ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506299
17ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506317
18ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506308
19ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506301
20ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506307
21ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506302
22ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506313
23ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506322
24ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506323
25ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506324
26ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506292
27ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506293
28ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506334
29ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506342
30ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506343
31ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506338
32ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506359
33ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506333
34ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506327
35ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506355
36ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506347
37ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506346
38ª Jornada:  https://www.marcadores.com/futbol/espana/liga-bbva/?competitionRoundId=506332
```

Comment: gracias amigo Lucas Damian tus respuestas son excelentes me estan ayudando mucho.

Comment: Tenia una pregunta como llegaste a la conclusion que debías de poner item.a.get   la  - a - en medio del item y del get , porque a mi no se ocurría ponerle, espero la respuesta amigo

Comment: Hola @Fscode. Estás importando **bs4**, luego usas **bs4.BeautifulSoup** lo menos que se espera es que le des una mirada al código o a su doc, para saber que ofrece. Es lo típico cuando se trata de usar librerías (con independencia del lenguaje en que se trabaje). Te aseguro que la mayoría de los que ofrecen buenas ayudas han aprendido explorando código y documentación, casi todos son 90% autodidactas.

Comment: @Fscode pues si te fijas bien, en el HTML, cada href pertenece a un elemento <a>.  Cuando me pueda acercar a una computadora, editaré la respuesta para una mejor explicación.